# How do I skip a requests response with no valid json?

Tags: json, python-2.7, python-requests

I am using requests as part of a geocoding process to loop through lots of text and return the coordinates like so:

```
for t in text:
    payload = {"q":t}
    located = requests.get("http://localhost:8999/CLIFF-2.1.1/parse/text", params=payload)
    l = located.json()
    for i in l['results']['places']['focus']:
        print i['name']
        print i['lat']
        print i['lon']
```

For the most part this works fine, but in some instances `No JSON object could be decoded`. Is there a way to skip past this bit of JSON and carry on iterating? (maybe a while loop?)

This is probably a really simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer...and it may be that I'm approaching this all wrong. Let me know if anything needs clarifying. Thanks in advance!

By the way, `text` is a list of text objects generated by another function.

Comment: *Is there a way to skip past this bit of JSON and carry on iterating?* im fairly certain the exception occurs in the `located.json()` call, so no there is no carry on iterating. You either have to catch the exception and skip everything if the json is erroneous, or write a json parser yourself

Comment: ok, thanks. i'll have to find an alternative method of doing this...

Comment: you might also want to check the `located.status_code` to see if there is any difference if no JSON returned.

Comment: I checked with `status_code ` and `raise_for_status ` and get a `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request`. Thing is I already knew it was a bad request! Not really sure where to go with it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply catch the `ValueError` that is raised when the `json` module can't decode the response, and then [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) with your iteration over `text`:

```
for t in text:
    payload = {"q": t}
    located = requests.get("http://localhost:8999/CLIFF-2.1.1/parse/text", params=payload)

    try:
        l = located.json()
    except ValueError:
        # No JSON object could be decoded - skip this item
        # and continue with the next item in `text`
        continue

    for i in l['results']['places']['focus']:
        print i['name']
        print i['lat']
        print i['lon']
```